# How to fix : Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, bson

I have an ASP.NET API to handle data going to a Mongo database. I need to also send some dynamic / irregular data for a number of documents, that'll have a couple of extra properties.

I'm trying to use [this cod](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/examples/mixing_static_and_dynamic/)e from the official tutorial, however I'm getting this error

```
Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonString' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'.
```

This is the code from the model class:

```
public class Incident
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string? Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Name")] 
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [BsonExtraElements]
    public BsonDocument? ExtraElements { get; set; }
}
```

This is the controller code

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class IncidentController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IncidentService _incidentService;

    public IncidentController(IncidentService incidentService)
    {
        _incidentService = incidentService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<List<Incident>> Get() =>
        await _incidentService.GetAllIncidents();
}
```

And the service

```
 public async Task<List<Incident>> GetAllIncidents() =>
        await _incidents.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
```

Strangely, the crash also happens in Swagger in POST, before I actually execute the operation.

Comment: What is `_incidents`? Is it `MongoCollection<Incident>` type? Meanwhile I think `await _incidents.Find().ToListAsync();` instead of `await _incidents.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();` The provide of `new BsonDocument()` is no needed if no filter. While the error message in title and question were different.

Comment: Even when posting the error is the same, just that it also crashes Swagger which is to be expected

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem and I solved it by returning `Json` instead of `BsonDocument`. In your case you can transform the list to `Json`.

Answer (score 0):

ExtraElement field is a boolen value in Database but you trying to convert list

Comment: But this happens even with an empty database collection or with one that respect the values types (manually uploaded with Compass).

Answer (score 0):

Just had this exact error. Turns out I had conflicting references with regards to Bson types.

Comment: I removed the question, please move it into a comment.